# cancel the drag operation on UISlider based on slider value

Tags: iphone, webkit, uislider

I have n number of sliders on a page representing percentage values. obviously the percentage should not be allowed to exceed a total of 100% across the n sliders.

so if the current totat of n-1 sliders is 90, then when the nth slider is being dragged, I would like to stop it at 10.

any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

In your action method that is called on `UIControlEventValueChanged`, compute the maximum allowable value for `sender`, and if its actual value is greater than the maximum, set `sender.value` to the maximum allowable value.

Edit: I just tried this approach with 2 sliders and it works great. This is the action method that is called when any one of the two sliders gets updated:

```
- (IBAction)sliderValueChanged:(id)sender
{
    UISlider *currentSlider = (UISlider *)sender;
    UISlider *otherSlider = currentSlider == self.slider1 ? self.slider2 : self.slider1;

    static float maxSum = 100.0f;
    float currentSum = currentSlider.value + otherSlider.value;

    if (currentSum > maxSum) {
        currentSlider.value = maxSum - otherSlider.value;
    }
}
```

Comment: yeah - i tried that, but that but the drag still happens, and the value and drag location go out of sync. i have a label that i update with the percentage value, and this label shows 100, while the slider is stuck at 80

Comment: Nope, you're wrong. I just tried it and it works perfectly. See my edit above. Of course, the sliders must be set to continuous updating.